# Android Studio 3.2.1 XML suggestion error

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I'm not getting required suggestions in the XML layout files
the suggestions only provide a single line of code for example
for a textView I'm getting only this much code `<TextView />` as a Suggestion
Other suggestions are not even visible like `gravity`, `id`, `weight`, etc...
I have tried `Invalidate caches`,
deleting .idea,
power Save mode and nothing worked for me.

Comment: it can be a lint problem , go to File > Setting  and search for lint xml and check if all are checked

Comment: Thanks mate all the things where checked but I just unchecked and checked it again and the problem is solved